# Trying to Filter Sheet using Cell in another Sheet

Tags: excel, vba

So my first sheet is the "Macro" button sheet which contains all of the Macros I use to manipulate data in the workbook and I'm trying to make a button that takes the input in a specific cell and then filter the sheet containing the data to only rows containing the input value.

I'm receiving an `Run-time error '1004': AutoFilter method of Range class failed`

The button contains this code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim lr As Long
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Part List")
        lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
        .Range("A1:E" & lr).AutoFilter field:=5, Criteria1:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Macro").Cells(1, 1).Value
    End With
End Sub
```

This is the 'Macro' Sheet
[image: Macro Page]

This is the page that the button macro is attempting to filter
[image]

Comment: but your range only has one column: `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Part List").Range("A1:A" & lr)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your criteria consist of one value ony, hence no array for it nor `Operator:=xlFilterValues` parameter

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim lr As Long
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Part List")
        lr = .Cells(.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
        .Range("A1:A" & lr).AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Macro").Cells(1, 1).Value
    End With
End Sub
```

where I also adopted `field:=1` since your "database" consists of 1 column only (Range("A1:A" & lr))

should you actually need to filter on column "E" (fifth column starting from A) then just change

```
.Range("A1:A" & lr).AutoFilter field:=1
```

to

```
.Range("A1:E" & lr).AutoFilter field:=5
```

Comment: @BigBen, yes I was noticing it while reviewing the answer… edited

Comment: So i noticed using Field=5 produced the Runtime 1004 Error and if remove it just filters my data sheet to just the header. I forgot to write the Range from `(A1:G)`

Comment: it suffices A:E, other columns will be filtered along

Comment: I updated my code to match what you placed, and I changed to filter column E using A1:E as you suggested but I'm still getting the Runtime 1004 Error.

Comment: This is the line: `.Range("A1:E" & lr).AutoFilter field:=5, Criteria1:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Macro").Cells(1, 1).Value`

Comment: well place some msgboxes before it like `Msgbox .Range("A1:A" & lr).Address` and `Msgbox ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Macro").Cells(1, 1).Value`, and let's see...

Comment: The first box output $A$1:$A$3 and then it spit out the Runtime Error .

Comment: then there is no "Macro" sheet in the workbook the macro belongs to

Comment: So the Macro sheet is the first sheet with the just the button and the cell containing the key. The button should be trying to filter Part List, looking at the code you provided it "appears" that its taking the cell value from Macro and filtering Part List

Comment: that was derived from your original code: you coded `arr = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Macro").Cells(1, 1).Value` and then `...Criteria1:=arr...`

Comment: Yeah that should be correct arr was the value I could type in and then it filtered Part List with Criteria1. I noticed the Runtime error keeps appearing when I set Field=5. Even if I have the range as `A:E`

Comment: Since, as you said, the 2nd box spits out the Runtime Error, then the flaw is in `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Macro").Cells(1, 1).Value` part of the statement. And the only subpart that can cause any error is `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Macro")` -> there is no such "Macro" sheet in the workbook where the macro resides. You have o work in that direction

Comment: Would referencing the Sheet by index resolve that issue possibly? Also to add if I set it to Field = 1 then the second box returns the value I have in A1. But when it is set to Field = 5 it returns the runtime error.

Comment: If the 2nd box, as per my suggestions, is the outcome of `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Macro").Cells(1, 1).Value`, it is not affected by the number you set the `Field` parameter to. Please check carefully it all

Comment: I've checked everything twice and I cannot seem to understand why if I change the Field = 5 I get the run-time error. I've updated my code and Included snippets of the workbook in case maybe I'm making an error someplace. But the button should be filtering the 2nd sheet's Program Column with what is written in A1 on the Macro Sheet.

Comment: If your _"2nd sheet"_ is named after "Part List" and is in the same workbook as "Macro" sheet, then the code I posted is ok. BTW, looking at posted images, there is a filter dropdown in _"2nd sheet"_ A2 cell: not sure it could affect anything but it's worth removing it. Let me know

Comment: Removing the Filter worked!, That filter must've been an artifact from a previous iteration of my code. I can't believe that was causing the Error. . .